# How to fix ajax call request

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

i'm trying to postback data via ajax on dropdown change but ajax call is not posting back to the controller

I am already trying to put a breakpoint to a controller to check but ajax call is not postback.

Html Code

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId",null,new { @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 ", required = "required", id = "CategoryDropDown",
        onchange="GetSubCategory()" })
</div> 

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<select id="SubCategory" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required"></select>
</div>
```

Ajax Code

```
    function GetSubCategory() {
        var stateId = $("#CategoryDropDown").val();
        $.ajax
            ({
                url: '/Home/GetSubCategory',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    stateId:+stateId
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#SubCategory").html("");
                    $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, SubCategory) {
                        $("#SubCategory").append($('<option></option>').val(SubCategory.Value).html(SubCategory.Text))
                    })
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")
                },
            });
    }
```

controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSubCategory(int stateId)
{
           JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string result = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Logics.SubCategory(MainCatId));
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I expected that ajax call work fine & I'm able to get sub-drop-down list from this method

Comment: have you debugged your javascript, is it going inside you `GetSubCategory` method on dropdown change?

Comment: nope its not going to subcategory action it always going to error:

Comment: Try catching the error in your error callback method and see what the error is
`error: function(request, status, errorThrown) {
     alert(status);
  }`

Comment: its shows just error in popup

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown))
Just try to debug all 3 parameters, you might get some clue

Comment: Check your network panel in the devtools of your browser. Check the response there.What error do you see?

Comment: 404 status code on GetSubCategory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST http://localhost/Home/GetSubCategory 404 (Not Found)
```

so you can see that there is no name of my project so i just correct mu ajax URL to

```
var url = "/AdminDevVersion/Home/GetSubCategory";
```

[The Problem was in URL when i see my console its showing 404 not found controller because of this url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjzP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `append` syntax should be like the following code:

```
$("#SubCategory").append($('<option value="'+ SubCategory.Value +'">' + SubCategory.Text + '</option>')
```

Comment: Make sur it runs till into success

Comment: yeah exactly its not going to success its always going to error

Comment: do this and check the error: error: `function (err) {console.log(err)}`

Comment: undefined appearing

Comment: So you're pb is more in your backend not in frontend

Comment: ? what do you mean? more backend not in frontend?

Comment: You need to check the code which provide your result. I mean you c# code and this `/Home/GetSubCategory`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

**edited**

```
   function GetSubCategory() {
        var stateId = $("#CategoryDropDown").val();
         var subCategory =  $("#SubCategory");
        $.ajax
            ({
                url: '/AdminDevVersion/Home/GetSubCategory',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ stateId:+stateId }),
                success: function (result) {
                 subCategory.empty(); // remove any existing options
                    $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, item) {
                        subCategory.append($('<option></option>').text(item.Text).val(item.Value))
                    })
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Whooaaa! Something went wrong..")
                },
            });
    }
```

Comment: same error @AlexandreRodrigues going to always error:

Comment: @AbdulAleemSolutions so if you try now with this url it works? Are you using Areas on your mvc project?